# Is 'neon' used in daily life to refer to modern things?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, metaphors

The words '新世紀' in the name of the anime '新世紀エヴァンゲリオン'(Neon Genesis Evangelion) means 'new era' literally, but in its English name, 'neon genesis' is used metaphorically.

A similar situation can be found in the classic song *The Sound of Silence* too, where 'neon god' is used to refer to modern technologies related things.

I wonder whether it's common to use the word 'neon' as a metaphor for 'modern' in daily life. If I use it in a small talk, can a random listener understand what I mean?

Is it used only in art or literature to make the works fancier? Considering the technology advance, is 'neon' a bit too old-fashioned since neon is actually an old technology? Is there a counterpart of 'neon' in use for nowadays?

Comment: My idea about 'neo genesis' is that 'neon' is kinda a metonymy for the epoch when the story happens. Hence it kinda indicates 'state-of-the-art'/new.

Comment: I think you mean "technology" rather than "technique"

Comment: @Esther Yep, part of my mind has been blank this whole time.

Comment: "Considering the technology advance, is 'neon' a bit too old-fashioned since neon is actually an old technology?" Yes, exactly.  Sound of silence was in the 60s, if you were to update the song the symbolisms used would be much different. Maybe it would be about social media and memes or the internet and ai  these days.  There's no "counterpart" to neon directly, because it never was a commonly used idiom, it's not like people were walking around and saying "that's so neon!!"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Not in my experience, no.

The imagery I associate with “neon” is specifically [neon lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lighting). It’s bright, it’s glary, it’s gaudy. It’s mainly used for business signage, so there’s an association with commercialism; the [Las Vegas Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_Strip) is something I picture here.

It’s modern, yes, but it’s a very specific aesthetic: everything neon is modern, but not everything modern is neon. It’s also not *very* modern—neon lighting and the associated aesthetic is from the 20th century.

Bright, gaudy, possibly commercial; that’s what I would expect my audience to think of if I used “neon” metaphorically in small talk. If I wanted to use it to refer to modernity more generally, I would have to do some work to establish that metaphor myself.

---

In *The Sound of Silence*, consider the earlier verses: “My eyes were stabbed by the flash of a neon light… And in the naked light I saw / Ten thousand people, maybe more”. Neon is bright and glary, painfully so. I think the contrast is light versus dark, not modern versus traditional.

As for *Neon Genesis Evangelion*, I think the average person would just see it as a [word salad title](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordSaladTitle). While “neon” does derive from the Greek for “new”, I don’t expect most people to think of “neon” as *meaning* “new”, any more than they think “evangelion” means “good news”/“Gospel”. (They likely wouldn’t actually be able to define “evangelion”, just associating it with religion and evangelicals).

The related “neo” (usually seen as a prefix… or as a *Matrix* character) does have the meaning “new”, so that’s an option.

As a side note, “genesis” is literally “beginning”/“creation”, not “era” (世 *sei*) nor “century” (世紀 *seiki*). Again, it has religious connotations, which is probably why it was chosen as the translation.

Comment: As someone who knows nothing about animes, it is indeed a word salad to me. Cool to learn about what it was meant to mean though.

Comment: Agreed about _The Sound of Silence_. It’s not a ‘modern god’ – it’s literally people worshipping neon signs, revelling in commercialism and capitalism.

Comment: As a reference point, it never even occurred to me to connect "evangelion" with "evangelical" or "evangelist", although I see the connection now. "Genesis" is the only part that conjured up anything to me at all, suggesting the general idea of "creation" (not necessarily Creation, in the religious sense).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I didn't mean 'neon god' is 'modern god'. I just understood 'neon god' to be (not exactly) something related to the society change brought about by the progress in science and especially techniques. It's a vague concept, though. I will try to explain it in more detail. In the 'good old days', people frequently talk to each other face to face and maybe heart to heart in some nostalgic dudes' eye. People also used to do lots of other things that tighten their bonds. In a word, in the 'good old days', people used to be closely connected (that is, in some dudes' eye).

Comment: there is very little neon left in Vegas, with all those old signs in a museum. I'd say that neon has a retro feel, a specific point in the past.

Comment: @Michael "neon" in *The Sound of Silence* is used as a metaphor for commercialism and capitalism, not modernity, although the song implies that commercialism, etc are more modern phenomena.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet However, thanks to the newly progress in technique back when the song was written, skyscrapers are built everywhere in the big cities and neon light can be seen in the commercial streets. Yet it doesn't seem to be a gospel in some ones' eyes. Those skyscrapers may be indeed splendid but living in an apartment quite tiny compared to those high-rises in the surroundings just make you feel like locked in a cage made of steel and concrete, which adds to modern people' solitude. (To be continued...)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The scene of neon light may be beautiful, but if you are not in the mood to have lots of fun there, it just makes you feel like an outsider (of the society or modern age?), which yet again adds to modern people's loneliness. The modern life seems to be lack of the warmth of humanity. It's in this sense that I feel the 'neon' indicates something related to modern society-- a lack of attention to people's heart, which is taken away by the pursue of profits and amusement.

Comment: @Michael Then we’re in agreement, apart from Esther’s point that neon represents specifically _capitalism_ and _consumerism_ (and their side effects, such as huge metropoleis and grey, industrialist blocks of tiny flats), rather than just technological progress and ‘modern’ stuff in general.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why is capitalism and consumerism the only concern of the 'neon' in the song? I think the movie from which the song is originated is more about the internal struggles and loneliness of a young guy rather than capitalism or consumerism. A song in a movie needs to help creating the atmosphere or expressing the theme in a musical way, right? Therefore, it doesn't make much sense to restrict the 'neon' to only capitalism and consumerism.

Comment: @Michael Precisely because ‘neon’ is _not_ normally used as an allegory for modern life, but it _is_ commonly used for advertisements, consumerism and capitalism. Simon may have intended something else here, but he couldn’t expect people to understand the reference if he did. The song didn’t originate from the movie (I’m assuming you mean _The Graduate_) – it predates it by three or four years – so I don’t think you can use the character’s struggles in the movie as a basis for analysing the song.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I didn't even realize OP was referencing the movie there, I was just confused about the "young man" in *The Sound of Silence*

Comment: I do not know if this is widespread, but for me personally "Neon" brings images of the 80s.  LED has almost completely replaced Neon where it used to be used, including the famous Neon vistas in Las Vegas and Hong Kong, and is not something I would associate with modernity anymore.  It's also deeply entwined with the 'cyberpunk' aesthetic which despite being set in the future, aesthetically is drawn from that same era.

Comment: In *The Sound of Silence*, the neon light is originally invoked as a bit of a metaphor, and then extended later as a kind of new god - possibly indeed riffing on the Greek origin of the word, but not in such a way that stands by itself.

Comment: Note that most "Neon lights" are not actually neon but other gases.  Neon lights are the reddish-orange ones.  Other colors use other gases, e.g. hydrogen, helium, CO2, krypton, argon, nitrogen, etc.  (Hence the incorrectness of terms such as "neon green" or "neon pink".  But most people don't care about chemical accuracy...)

Answer (score 17):

No.

Neon, either means the chemical element, an inert gas.  It therefore means the lights that use this gas to produces a bright red light. The lights can be made into curved tubes and used to spell words for signs outside places like casinos.  This is the metaphor in the song, it doesn't mean "new god" (though it could be a secondary reference, a piece of word-play).

As an adjective it means "bright, florescent":  "He was wearing neon yellow socks" means the bright yellow socks that seems to glow. You might use a neon highlighter pen when studying.

It never means new.

Answer (score 13):

The title *Neon Genesis Evangelion* is in Greek, not English.  One way to translate it is, “Creation of New Gospels.”  The word *neon* by itself is [the plural neuter genitive of the Greek word for “new.” (In this context, it could not be singular.)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BD%CE%AD%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek)  In the original Japanese, the title was, *Shinseiki Evangerion*.  The translator decided to replace the Japanese word, which would be totally unfamiliar to an English-speaking audience, with Greek words that would be vaguely familiar.

I think describing something as “neon” would make most Americans think of the bright color of neon signs (in American English, “neon lights” include colorful electric lights containing other gases, but not fluorescent lamps the color of natural light), or metaphorically, of the gaudiness of downtown Las Vegas.

Comment: Note that if _neon_ is indeed meant to be _νέον_ (nominative-accusative singular neuter), then the title makes no sense in Greek – it becomes just ‘creation new gospel’. If the title is supposed to actually make sense in Greek, both _neon_ and _evangelion_ should be in the genitive instead. In the singular, that would be _neou evangeliou_ (_νέου εὐαγγελίου_), which doesn’t fit, but with a plural, it still fits: _νέων γένεσις εὐαγγελίων_ ‘creation of new gospels’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good points; I edited my translation accordingly.

Comment: I *think* the genesis is meant to be capital-c creation.  So 'new gospels about the beginning/creation' (overriding the old gospels) is how I've always seen it.  But I don't know Greek except for the alphabet.  Is that a valid interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly no, largely because neon's been around for more than 100 years. It might have retained 'state-of-the-art' newness as a metaphor for 'modern' until not-long before the Moon landings but like The Sound of Silence, those are today “so last century." (Though they seem like yesterday to people like me. Ouch!)

If it ever was common to use "neon" as a metaphor for "modern" that wasn't "in daily life" and it's no longer a thing.

That is indeed a way of agreeing "neon" is too old-fashioned since it's an old *technology*.

One counterpart of "neon" in use *nowadays* might be "silicon" which could already be passé but certainly isn't alone.  Others include "wet-ware" meaning brain matter as opposed to hard- or soft-ware…

There are also inverted references such as "snail-mail" comparing slow traditional paper post to nearly-instant e-mail.

I doubt "neon" is still used to make literature or other arts "fancier"… if it ever was. Did *The Sound of Silence* try to make itself "fancier" or did it legitimately use a colourful (no pun intended), graphic term for dynamic effect? The point being that "fancier" is more about a bogus method than a better result.

Is it fair to cite '新世紀' or '新世紀エヴァンゲリオン' without English phonetic spelling and full literal translations? Still, "neon genesis" is much too far from "new era" to be anything but an artificial construct, forced upon the words for the convenience of the author.

"If I used it in a small talk, can a random listener understand what I mean" throws up more and different topics.

Quite separately, "random listeners" are people met in lifts or queues with whom we have nothing apparent in common. What we say to them is at best "chit chat", which has even less value than ”small talk."

By contrast "small talk" is with people we have at least some reason to *want* to be with, as on dates or at parties…

Further ”a small talk" always means "a short lecture”; never social intercourse.

Beneath any of that, the parts of any sentence must match in number, tense and every other way: you need either "If I *use* it… *can* a listener… ?" or "If I *used* it… *could* a listener… ?"